# How reliable is window.location.hostname?

Tags: javascript

We're trying to make it harder to embed our website in other websites (iframe or otherwise) and check window.location.hostname to see if it's our domain or not.

Now, when someone saves a file for offline use, seems this property is empty, which is fine.

Can we trust it not to be empty in online situations or not to be easily falsified?

We're aware that this isn't a fail safe method of prevention as another website could download the content and Javascript separately and then mash and display them. However, like other means of protection, it's supposed to stop the ones who don't try to specifically target us but generally do that.

Comment: [psst](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 1):

I thik it's very reliable. But since you want to use it inside iframe you want to use this one.

```
window.top.location
```

It'll get the parent's `location` instance. I hope this will help you. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for answering but "I think" isn't what I was looking for. I think so as well but didn't find official resources to support it or counter it. I'm aware of using the top frame, thanks.